# How to match all keys related to time in json in Python

Tags: python, json

I have json data which has key related to time. It looks like below:

```
{
   "tag": {
         "recordTime": "1433522419",
         "eventtime": "1433522419",
         "activeTime": "1433522419",
         "data": [{
             "dataType": "proximity",
             "dataValue": [{
                   "time":"1433522419",
                   "value": 34
               }, {
                   "time":"1433522419",
                   "value": 39
               }, {
                   "time":"1433522419",
                   "value": 45
               }]
             }]
 }
```

This data contains time values which are in unix epoch time. I need to convert it into local date time format. Is there any way I can get all these values and convert to date time.

Comment: Question is unclear. "Match all keys related to time" -- how? How can Python know if it's a time or just an integer? Do the jsons always have this structure?

Comment: @Denziloe Yes this structure always

Comment: So you're not really trying to "match" anything, you can just get the appropriate fields from the json and modify them. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime   

times = {}

times['recordTime'] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(jsonObj['tag']['recordTime']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
times['eventtime'] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(jsonObj['tag']['eventtime']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

then you can go through all the tags doing that. You can change the formatting of the date by moving around or removing the %Y-%m-%d part. Full docs here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior